# Smooth convex hull of a large data set of 3D points

Tags: computational-geometry

I recently needed to deal with a large data set of 600,000 points in three dimensions. My task was to find a convex hull for this data. I have *Mathematica* 10, so I could use the function `ConvexHullMesh`; I obtained this:

[image: screenshot]
[image: convex hull]

I was wondering if there is some way to find a smooth convex hull (maybe an ellipsoid) for my data.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'smooth convex hull', or, how is an ellipsoid a convex hull for your data? Could you explain that a bit.

Comment: I second user21's question; there is no standard notion of a "smooth convex hull". If you really really want an ellipsoid, you could try finding the [minimum-volume ellipsoid enclosing your set of points](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/emo/PublFiles/SmallEnclDisk_LNCS555_91.pdf).

Comment: Yes, I mean, smooth convex hull as differential function. So, the other comment is probably that I need. I'll read the paper, and If I success, I write hear my trie.

Comment: There are routines to calculate MVE ellipsoids in MATLAB. You could just translate one to *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Minimum Volume Ellipsoid**

Translated from [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9542-minimum-volume-enclosing-ellipsoid), this uses the Khachiyan algorithm, and should work for any dimension.

```
    MinVolEllipse[P_, tolerance_] := 
     Module[{d, n, Q, count, err, u, X, M, maximum, j, stepSize, newu, U, A, c},

      {n, d} = Dimensions[P];
      Q = Append[1] /@ P;

      count = 1;
      err = 1;
      u = ConstantArray[1./n, n];

      While[err > tolerance,
       X = Q\[Transpose].DiagonalMatrix[u].Q;
       M = Diagonal[Q.Inverse[X].Q\[Transpose]];
       maximum = Max[M];
       j = Position[M, maximum][[1, 1]];
       stepSize = (maximum - d - 1)/((d + 1) (maximum - 1));
       newu = (1 - stepSize) u;
       newu[[j]] += stepSize;
       count += 1;
       err = Norm[newu - u];
       u = newu;
       ];

      U = DiagonalMatrix[u];

      A = (1/d) Inverse[P\[Transpose].U.P - Outer[Times, u.P, u.P]];
      c = u.P;

      {c, A}
      ]
```

Usage:

```
    pts = RandomVariate[
       MultinormalDistribution[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2}], 
        With[{m = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}]}, m.m\[Transpose]]], 500];

    P = MeshCoordinates[ConvexHullMesh[pts]];
    tolerance = 0.0001;

    {c, A} = MinVolEllipse[P, tolerance];

    X = {x, y};
    Show[
     ConvexHullMesh[pts],
     Graphics[{
       Point[pts],
       {Red, Point[P]}
       }],
     ContourPlot[(X - c).A.(X - c) == 1, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
     ]
```

[image]

In 3D:

```
    pts = RandomVariate[
       MultinormalDistribution[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3}], 
        With[{m = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 3}]}, m.m\[Transpose]]], 100];

    P = MeshCoordinates[ConvexHullMesh[pts]];
    tolerance = 0.0001;

    {c, A} = MinVolEllipse[P, tolerance];

    X = {x, y, z};
    Show[
     ConvexHullMesh[pts, MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> Opacity[0.5, Green]}],
     Graphics3D[{
       Point[pts],
       {Red, Point[P]}
       }],
     ContourPlot3D[(X - c).A.(X - c) == 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3},
      ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.2]]
      ]
     ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here is a **faster** implementation of the Khachiyan minimum-volume ellipsoid algorithm, using updating formulae presented in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.dam.2007.02.013):

```
mve[pts_?MatrixQ, tol_: 1.*^-8] := 
    Module[{prec = Precision[pts], bet, bm, c, d, del, dp, h, j, kap, n,
            qj, qm, sc, sig, u, zero},
           zero = SetPrecision[0, prec]; {n, d} = Dimensions[pts]; dp = d + 1;
           qm = PadRight[pts, {n, dp}, N[1, prec]]; 
           u = N[ConstantArray[1/n, n], prec];
           bm = Transpose[qm].DiagonalMatrix[u].qm; 
           kap = Diagonal[qm.LinearSolve[bm, Transpose[qm]]];
           c = FixedPoint[(j = Ordering[kap, -1]; qj = Extract[qm, j];
                           sc = 1/Extract[kap, j]; sig = (1 - sc dp)/(1 - sc);
                           bet = sig/dp; h = 1 - bet; del = dp (1 - sc)/d;
                           kap = del (kap - sc sig (qm.LinearSolve[bm, qj])^2);
                           bm = h bm + bet Outer[Times, qj, qj];
                           h # + SparseArray[{j -> bet}, n, zero]) &, u, 
                          SameTest -> (SquaredEuclideanDistance[##] <= tol &)].pts;
           Ellipsoid[c, d (Drop[bm, -1, -1] - Outer[Times, c, c])]]
```

The routine returns an `Ellipsoid[]` object, suitable for display or any other further manipulations (e.g. one can apply an eigendecomposition to the matrix in the second argument of the `Ellipsoid[]` object to get the axes).

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            pts = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2}], 
                                With[{m = RandomReal[1, {2, 2}]}, m.Transpose[m]]], 1024];]

Graphics[{Red, mve[pts], Blue, MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[pts], 2], Yellow, Point[pts]}]
```

[image: minimum-volume ellipse and 2D convex hull]

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "Rule30CA"]; 
            pts = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3}], 
                                With[{m = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]}, Transpose[m].m]], 1024];]

Graphics3D[{Opacity[1/2, Red], mve[pts], Blue, MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[pts], 2]}]
```

[image: minimum-volume ellipsoid and 3D convex hull]