# Draw bounding region by list of points

Tags: plotting, regions, computational-geometry

Suppose you have a list of data points, either in 2D or 3D; is it possible to plot the minimal bounding region containing all the points?

Ignoring holes etc.

Comment: my gut instinct is that InterpolationPoint might be the option to consider

Comment: Are you looking for `ConvexHullMesh`?

Comment: Exactly! is there a way to apply smoothing to it? and perhaps some opacity?

Comment: Opacity: sure, it's somewhere in the options. What do you mean by "smoothing" though? Do you have an example in mind?

Comment: It seems convexhullmesh will give a quite polygonal/linear shape. Is there anyway to somehow round the shape?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57838).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the 2D case, you can use the shape of the joint to give rounded corners to your shape. For instance:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {20, 2}];
ConvexHullMesh[pts]
```

[image: hull]

Retrieve the mesh expressed as a `Polygon` object and style to your liking:

```
Graphics[{
  Darker@Blue, 
  EdgeForm[{Darker@Blue, Thickness[0.09], JoinForm["Round"]}],
  Cases[Normal[chm["Graphics"]], _Polygon, All]
}]
```

[image: styled]

Comment: Awesome, thanks again!

Comment: @MKF You are welcome!

Answer (score 8):

Given a set of random 3D points, you can create a mesh that represents the minimum bounding region using `BoundingRegion[]` or `ConvexHullMesh[]` as MarcoB suggested. `ConvexHullMesh[]` is probably the simplest, though `BoundingRegion[]` has some nice options for other sorts of regions like the smallest sphere or cuboid.

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1234]; pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 3}];]
cvx = ConvexHullMesh[pts]
br = BoundingRegion[pts, "MinConvexPolyhedron"]
```

This should give you two meshes that look identical to this:

[image: Convex hull mesh of random 3d points.]

You can choose whichever function you prefer. It's also possible to show the points themselves along with the mesh:

```
Show[HighlightMesh[br, Style[2, Opacity[0.5]]], Graphics3D[Point[pts]]]
```

[image: Convex hull mesh of random 3d points with points shown.]