# Verify a conjectured formula for a modification of a 3D constrained integration successfully solved using Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, physics, geometry, boolean-computation, constraint

I've acquired somewhat indirect--and not fully conclusive--evidence that the solution of a certain three-dimensional constrained integration takes the form

```
1/576 (8 - 6 Sqrt[2] + 15 Sqrt[2] \[Pi] - 48 Sqrt[2] ArcTan[Sqrt[2]])
```

$\approx 0.00227243$. My question here is whether this conjecture can be formally verified (needless to say, with the use of Mathematica).

The problem in question is a modification of the three-dimensional integration successfully and quite impressively solved by user JimB in the answer

```
29902415923/497664 - 50274109/(512 Sqrt[2]) - (3072529845 π)/(32768 Sqrt[2]) +(1024176615 ArcCos[1/3])/(4096 Sqrt[2])
```

$\approx 0.00365826$

to [Original3Dproblem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral) .

The specific integration problem for which we seek to verify our candidate  solution (following the notation of [Original3Dproblem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral)) is

```
Integrate[Boole[Subscript[λ, 1] > Subscript[λ, 2] && Subscript[λ, 2] > Subscript[λ, 3] &&Subscript[λ, 3] > 1 - Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ, 3] && Subscript[λ, 1] -Subscript[λ, 3] < 2 Sqrt[Subscript[λ, 2] (1 - Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ,3])]], {Subscript[λ, 3], 0, 1}, {Subscript[λ, 2], 0, 1}, {Subscript[λ, 1], 0, 1}]  .
```

The  (unmodified) question [Original3Dproblem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral) was also posed in constrained form, but converted to an unconstrained form employing a transformation suggested by N. Tessore,

```
change = {Subscript[λ, 1] -> x/(1 + 2 x), Subscript[λ, 2] -> y/(1 + y) (1 + x)/(1 + 2 x),Subscript[λ, 3] -> z 1/(1 + y) (1 + x)/(1 + 2 x)},
```

which clearly remains applicable for the present (modified) question, leading to the transformed unconstrained problem at hand

```
Integrate[(1 + x)^2/((1 + 2 x)^4 (1 + y)^3), {z, 1/2, 1}, {y, z, 2 + 2Sqrt[1 - z] - z}, {x, y, 2 Sqrt[-((-y - 2 y^2 - y^3 + y z + 2 y^2 z + y^3 z)/(-1 + y + z)^4)] + ( 4 y + z - 3 y z - z^2)/(-1 + y + z)^2}],
```

also conjecturally yielding the formula given at the outset.

Although we have not (yet) been able to solve this problem directly, we have solved--using Mathematica--the associated 2D-integration for the boundary area of the convex set, modifying the inequality constraint

```
 Subscript[λ, 1] -Subscript[λ, 3] < 2 Sqrt[Subscript[λ, 2] (1 - Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ,3])]
```

to the equality constraint

```
 Subscript[λ, 1] -Subscript[λ, 3] == 2 Sqrt[Subscript[λ, 2] (1 - Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ,3])].
```

The solution to this 2D problem we did find to be

```
1/96 (8 - 6 Sqrt[2] + 15 Sqrt[2] \[Pi] - 48 Sqrt[2] ArcTan[Sqrt[2]])
```

$\approx 0.013634585$.

The key to obtaining our conjectured formula

```
1/576 (8 - 6 Sqrt[2] + 15 Sqrt[2] \[Pi] - 48 Sqrt[2] ArcTan[Sqrt[2]])
```

for which we seek verification here, is that we found the (area/volume) ratio of 0.013634585916219 to a numerical integration estimation (0.002272430980282073) of the solution to the 3D-problem to  be 6.000000015193957, clearly pointing to an exact value of 6.

If the area/volume ratio is, in fact, 6, then this might serve as a useful clue in identifying the specific nature of the set in question, if it falls within known categories. (As simply an example, a three-dimensional ball of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ has such a ratio.)

The modification pursued here consists in replacing the (Hilbert-Schmidt [eq. (15.35)] [GeometryQuantumStates](https://chaos.if.uj.edu.pl/%7Ekarol/geometry.htm)) integrand in [Original3Dproblem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral)

```
9081072000 (Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 2])^2 (Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 3])^2 (Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ, 3])^2 (-1 + 2 Subscript[λ, 1] + Subscript[λ, 2] + Subscript[λ, 3])^2 (-1 + Subscript[λ, 1] + 2 Subscript[λ, 2] + Subscript[λ, 3])^2 (-1 + Subscript[λ, 1] + Subscript[λ, 2] + 2 Subscript[λ, 3])^2
```

by simply 1.

The motivation behind this modification was that rather than considering the problem as that of the four ordered eigenvalues of a (Hermitian, nonnegative-definite $4 \times 4$, trace 1) "two-qubit density matrix"  in the 15-dimensional setting for such  such matrices, we simply now focus on the 3-dimensional convex set $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, 1-\lambda_1-\lambda_2-\lambda_3)$  of "ordered spectra of absolutely separable two-qubit density matrices".

We are interested in this problem because its solution would yield the Euclidean volume of that indicated convex set for which we aspire [JohnEllipsoidProblem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234589/graph-construct-john-ellipsoids-circumscribing-and-inscribing-a-certain-3d-con) to find the "John ellipsoids" of minimal and maximal volumes circumscribing and inscribing it.

Comment: Is this a question about Mathematica? This seems like it might be more appropriate for [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), maybe [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). It could also use some editing to make clear what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: N.J.Evans--thanks! I've done a lot or reorganizing to try to bring the Mathematica aspects to the fore, and putting the motivation/background later in the question statement.

Answer (score 4):

For your first question $\frac{1}{2} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)-\frac{\pi }{8}$ is equivalent to $\csc ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{6 \left(\sqrt{2}+2\right)}\right)$ so the equation can be simplified to

```
1/288 (4 - 3 Sqrt[2] - 6 Sqrt[2] ArcCsc[3] + 12 Sqrt[2] ArcCsc[Sqrt[6 (2 + Sqrt[2])]]) /. 
  ArcCsc[Sqrt[6 (2 + Sqrt[2])]] -> -(π/8) + 1/2 ArcCos[1/3] /. 
  ArcCsc[3] -> π/2 - ArcCos[1/3] // Expand // Together

(*  1/576 (8 - 6 Sqrt[2] - 9 Sqrt[2] π + 24 Sqrt[2] ArcCos[1/3]) *)
```

as in previous questions you seemed to desire the term `ArcCos[1/3}` to be included.

The next part is to use *Mathematica* to end up with that result.

Taking the `Boole` part of the formula one can end up with 5 integrations to be performed:

```
Reduce[Subscript[λ, 1] > Subscript[λ, 2] && Subscript[λ, 2] > Subscript[λ, 3] && 
  Subscript[λ, 3] > 1 - Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ, 3] && 
  Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 3] < 2 Sqrt[Subscript[λ, 2] (1 - Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ, 3])]]
```

And after some manipulations of that result one ends up with 5 regions to integrate over:

[image: Regions to integrate over]

Next one performs the individual integrations:

Integration 1

```
i1 = Integrate[1, {λ1, 1/4, 1/3}, {λ2, 1/3 (1 - λ1), λ1}, {λ3, 1/2 (1 - λ1 - λ2), λ2}]
(* 1/3888 *)
```

Integration 2:

```
i2 = Integrate[1, {λ1, 1/3, 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2])}, 
  {λ2, 1/3 (1 - λ1), 1/9 (2 - λ1) + 2/9 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2]}, 
  {λ3, 1/2 (1 - λ1 - λ2), λ2}]
(* (998-447 Sqrt[2]+972 Sqrt[2] ArcSin[1/54 (20-23 Sqrt[2])])/62208 *)
```

The 3rd integration results in some complicated square root functions and the [denestSqrt](http://https%20:%20//%20%20%20mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230686/how%20-%20do%20-%20i%20-%20%20%20%20suppress%20-%20an%20-%20automatic%20-%20sign%20-%20change%20-%20ii) function from @CarlWoll is used.

```
denestSqrt[e_, domain_, x_] := Replace[y /. Solve[Simplify[Reduce[Reduce[y == e && domain, x], y, Reals], domain], y], {{r_} :> r, _ -> e}]

i3a = Integrate[1, {λ2, 1/9 (2 - λ1) + 2/9 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2], λ1}, 
  {λ3, 1/2 (1 - λ1 - λ2), λ1 - 2 λ2 + 2 Sqrt[λ2 - 2 λ1 λ2]}, 
    Assumptions -> {1/3 < λ1 <= 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2])}] // Expand;
i3a = i3a /. Sqrt[1 - 2 λ1] Sqrt[2 - λ1 + 2 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2]] -> 
  denestSqrt[Sqrt[(1 - 2 λ1) (2 - λ1 + 2 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2])], 1/3 < λ1 <= 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2]), λ1] /.
  Sqrt[1 - 2 λ1] λ1 Sqrt[2 - λ1 + 2 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2]] -> 
  denestSqrt[λ1 Sqrt[(1 - 2 λ1) (2 - λ1 + 2 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2])], 
  1/3 < λ1 <= 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2]), λ1] /.
  Sqrt[1 - 2 λ1] Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2] Sqrt[2 - λ1 + 2 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2]] -> 
  denestSqrt[Sqrt[(1 - 2 λ1) (1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2) (2 - λ1 + 2 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2])], 
  1/3 < λ1 <= 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2]), λ1] // Expand;
i3a1 = Integrate[-(1/81), {λ1, 1/3, 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2])}];
i3a2 = Integrate[-((50 λ1)/81), {λ1, 1/3, 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2])}];
i3a3 = Integrate[4/3 Sqrt[1 - 2 λ1] λ1^(3/2), {λ1, 1/3, 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2])}] // ToRadicals;
i3a4 = Integrate[(77 λ1^2)/81, {λ1, 1/3, 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2])}];
i3a5 = Integrate[-(1/81) Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2], {λ1, 1/3, 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2])}];
i3a6 = Integrate[-(10/81) λ1 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2], {λ1, 1/3, 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2])}];
i3 = i3a1 + i3a2 + i3a3 + i3a4 + i3a5 + i3a6 // Expand
(* -(329/31104)+133/(31104 Sqrt[2])-ArcSin[1/54 (20-23 Sqrt[2])]/(96 Sqrt[2])+ArcSin[1/2 Sqrt[1/3 (2-Sqrt[2])]]/(24 Sqrt[2]) *)
```

Integration 4

```
i4 = Integrate[1, {λ1, 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2]), 1/2}, 
  {λ2, 1/3 (1 - λ1), 1/9 (2 - λ1) + 2/9 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2]}, 
  {λ3, 1/2 (1 - λ1 - λ2), λ2}]
(* (-2+149 Sqrt[2]-324 Sqrt[2] ArcCos[1/6 (4+Sqrt[2])])/20736 *)
```

Integration 5:

```
i5a = Integrate[1, {λ2, 1/9 (2 - λ1) + 2/9 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2],
  1/9 (5 - 7 λ1) + 4/9 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2]}, 
  {λ3, 1/2 (1 - λ1 - λ2), λ1 - 2 λ2 + 2 Sqrt[λ2 - 2 λ1 λ2]}, 
  Assumptions -> {1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2]) < λ1 < 1/2}] // Expand;

i5a = i5a /. Sqrt[1 - 2 λ1] Sqrt[2 - λ1 + 2 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2]] ->
  denestSqrt[Sqrt[(1 - 2 λ1) (2 - λ1 + 2 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2])], 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2]) < λ1 < 1/2, λ1] /.
  Sqrt[1 - 2 λ1] λ1 Sqrt[2 - λ1 + 2 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2]] -> 
  λ1 denestSqrt[Sqrt[(1 - 2 λ1) (2 - λ1 + 2 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2])], 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2]) < λ1 < 1/2, λ1] /.
  Sqrt[1 - 2 λ1] Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2] Sqrt[2 - λ1 + 2 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2]] -> 
  denestSqrt[Sqrt[(1 - 2 λ1) (1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2) (2 - λ1 + 2 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2])], 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2]) < λ1 < 1/2, λ1] /.
  Sqrt[1 - 2 λ1] Sqrt[5 - 7 λ1 + 4 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2]] -> 
  denestSqrt[Sqrt[(1 - 2 λ1) (5 - 7 λ1 + 4 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2])], 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2]) < λ1 < 1/2, λ1] /.
  Sqrt[1 - 2 λ1] λ1 Sqrt[5 - 7 λ1 + 4 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2]] -> 
  λ1 denestSqrt[Sqrt[(1 - 2 λ1) (5 - 7 λ1 + 4 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2])], 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2]) < λ1 < 1/2, λ1] /.
  Sqrt[1 - 2 λ1] Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2] Sqrt[5 - 7 λ1 + 4 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2]] -> 
    denestSqrt[Sqrt[(1 - 2 λ1) (1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2) (5 - 7 λ1 + 4 Sqrt[1 - λ1 - 2 λ1^2])], 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2]) < λ1 < 1/2, λ1] // Expand
(* 7/324+(2 λ1)/81-(11 λ1^2)/81+1/27 Sqrt[1-λ1-2 λ1^2]-2/27 λ1 Sqrt[1-λ1-2 λ1^2] *)
i5 = Integrate[i5a, {λ1, 1/8 (2 + Sqrt[2]), 1/2}]
(* (514-781 Sqrt[2]+972 Sqrt[2] ArcCos[1/6 (4+Sqrt[2])])/62208 *)
```

Adding them up together:

```
result = i1 + i2 + i3 + i4 + i5 // FullSimplify
1/288 (4 - 3 Sqrt[2] + 6 Sqrt[2] ArcCsc[Sqrt[6 (2 + Sqrt[2])]] + 3 Sqrt[2] ArcSin[1/54 (20 - 23 Sqrt[2])])
```

This can be further simplified to

```
result /. ArcSin[1/54 (20 - 23 Sqrt[2])] -> -((5 \[Pi])/4) + 3 ArcCos[1/3] /. 
   ArcCsc[Sqrt[6 (2 + Sqrt[2])]] -> -(\[Pi]/8) + 1/2 ArcCos[1/3] // Expand // Together
(* 1/576 (8 - 6 Sqrt[2] - 9 Sqrt[2] \[Pi] + 24 Sqrt[2] ArcCos[1/3]) *)
```

Comment: Thanks, JimB! I probably should have--for full consistency--employed this simplification, but I used a slight variation with ArcTan that I introduced in a revision of the original question.

Comment: Fabulous, JimB, as usual! Not too easy once again--despite the severe simplification of the integrand. Regarding the slight difference in  final formulas (in terms of inverse trigonometric formulas), when I use WolframAlpha for exact results based on high-precision numerics, it seems to always suggest alternatives based on use of the "magic angle" or "tetrahedral angle". This time I happened to pick the magic one--but probably for overall consistency, I should have picked the alternative.

Comment: Of course, one has better things to do--but I think it would be an interesting exercise to try to solve the problem in its original, constrained form. This must have been the way I pursued the original/unmodified challenging problem in 2009--the Tessore transformation not being available then. (The last answer to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral did pursue the constrained problem.)