# Fit ellipse to a arbitrary 2D image to extract centroid, orientation, major, minor axis

Tags: plotting, image-processing, fitting, image

I am wondering if there is an easy way to fit an ellipse into an arbitrary 2D image quickly, so its centroid, orientation, major, and minor axis length can directly be extracted. In MATLAB, this can be done using `regionprops` command quickly as shown in the following URL:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/495720-how-to-fit-an-ellipse-to-an-image-in-matlab

Comment: Do any answers from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25589/how-can-i-detect-an-ellipse-in-a-photo?rq=1 work?

Comment: Thanks, Adam! I looked at it as well, but it did not apply to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The similar command in MMA is `ComponentMeasurement`. It lists all detected bright components of an image with desired parameter.

```
a = Import[
  "https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/\
253610/diskimage1.jpeg"];

cm = ComponentMeasurements[
  Binarize@a, {"Centroid", "SemiAxes", "Orientation"}]
```

> {1 -> {{488.496, 386.124}, {750.908, 620.778}, 3.14156},
> 2 -> {{438.5, 868.5}, {3.66324, 2.63965}, -1.5708},
> 3 -> {{526.5, 868.87}, {3.31766, 2.55314}, -1.5708},
> 4 -> {{539., 871.}, {2.23607, 1.}, 3.14159},
> 5 -> {{513.864, 866.591}, {2.17306, 1.53368}, -2.87856},
> 6 -> {{499.6, 483.975}, {205.184, 190.328}, -0.834907},
> 7 -> {{349.5, 626.}, {1., 0.5}, -1.5708}}

The result contains more than one entry because the presence of the caption on top of the image together with white frame. The needed spot is number six (with second biggest value of simiaxes).

```
Show[Binarize@a,
 Epilog -> {
   Red,
   Rotate[
    Circle[cm[[6, 2, 1]], cm[[6, 2, 2]]], 
    cm[[6, 2, 3]]]
   },
 ImageSize -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

Relate  [Determine and plot major and minor axes of ellipse](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239753/determine-and-plot-major-and-minor-axes-of-ellipse/239758#239758)

We first trim the picture to remove the label, then we use `RemoveBackground`,and `ImageMesh` to generate the mesh.

Finally we use `BoundingRegion` to find the minimal ellipsoid and use `Eigensystem` to determinate the center and major and  minor.(Thanks @J. M.'s ennui)

```
pic = Import[
   "https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/\
253610/diskimage1.jpeg"];
trimpic = ImageTake[pic, {40, 700}];
mesh = ImageMesh@RemoveBackground@trimpic;
ellipsoid = BoundingRegion[mesh, "MinEllipse"];
center = ellipsoid // First;
{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[ellipsoid // Last];
{a, b} = Sqrt[vals];
major = {center - a vecs[[1]], center + a vecs[[1]]};
minor = {center - b vecs[[2]], center + b vecs[[2]]};

Show[trimpic, 
 Graphics[{{Red, PointSize[Large], Point@center, Blue, 
    Line[{major, minor}]}}], 
 Region[RegionBoundary[ellipsoid], 
  BaseStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[2], Red}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! I learn many commands for Mathematica image processing from your answer.